# Fig: how do I run commands on an existing container?

Tags: docker, fig

I have two containers running with `fig up`: web and db. I'd like to get some info about the environment where the web container is running: what env variables are set, read some logs that the web server has written, etc.

I know that containers are a bit like processes and you don't "log into" processes, but they're also in a way similar to VMs and you do log into them...

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you want to list your running containers:

```
docker ps
```

Then you can run a bash shell inside your running container using its ID or name:

```
docker exec -i -t 665b4a1e17b6 bash
docker exec -i -t container_name bash
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Docker v.1.3.3+ you can use [Docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec) to execute commands in your container. To get all env variables you can simply execute:

```
sudo docker exec [container ID or name] printenv
```

To read logs that are written to STDOUT and STDERR you can use [Docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#logs).